# WebView Opening White Screen Randomly while showing PDF from Google Docs

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to Open a PDF on a URL in Webview. It works Perfectly fine. But sometimes When we open the WebviewActivity, it displays a White blank screen and pdf is not shown. It happens in every 1 case out of 5 tries. Below is my code for Webview Client. Any kind help is appreciated.

```
   class MonkeyWebViewClient2 : WebViewClient {
        ImageView _imgViewBack,_imgViewForward, _imgRefresh;
        public MonkeyWebViewClient2(ImageView imgViewBack,ImageView imgViewForward,ImageView imgRefresh){
            _imgViewBack = imgViewBack;
            _imgViewForward = imgViewForward;
            _imgRefresh = imgRefresh;
        }


        public override void OnPageStarted (WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted (view, url, favicon);

            _imgRefresh.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.close);
            if(view.CanGoBack()){
                _imgViewBack.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.back_black_arrow);
            }else {
                _imgViewBack.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.NavArrowLeft);
            }
            if (view.CanGoForward()) {
                _imgViewForward.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ArrowRight2);
            } else {
                _imgViewForward.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.NavArrowRight);
            } 
            _imgRefresh.Click += (sender, e) => view.StopLoading ();
            //Console.WriteLine ("OnPageStarted");
        }
        public override void OnPageFinished (WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished (view, url);

            _imgRefresh.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.refresh_icon);
            if (view.CanGoBack ()) {
                _imgViewBack.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.back_black_arrow);
            } else {
                _imgViewBack.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.NavArrowLeft);
            }
            if (view.CanGoForward ()) {
                _imgViewForward.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ArrowRight2);
            } else {
                _imgViewForward.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.NavArrowRight);
            } 
            _imgRefresh.Click += (sender, e) => view.Reload ();

            AndHUD.Shared.Dismiss();

        }
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        if (InformationWebView != null)
        {
            InformationWebView.OnPause();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if (InformationWebView != null)
        {
            InformationWebView.OnResume();
        }
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed (){
        Finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen when you come back to this page from another or just when you directly open it?

Comment: It happens when I come back to this page from another @G.hakim

Comment: Thought so, you might wanna reload the page when you come back to it sometimes it loses its old state

Comment: No, I am every time creating a new instance of Activity for it. so old state retaining is not here. @G.hakim

Comment: Event Code executes till webview.loadURL(url).
But control doesn't comes inside onPageStarted() of the WebView Client. @G.hakim

Comment: it does not make sense to create a new instance of it rather just reload the webview that is much easier

Comment: But Everytime webview.Load(url) is called. so whole webview is sort of Reloaded.

Comment: That is the whole point

Comment: @G.hakim: I Didn't get it. I mean if everytime loadURL is called, then why do we need to reload the webview again? and why it is coming as blank screen?